# CSS - Trying to set the same height for three images with different sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem setting up three images to be the same size. My issue is that I have three images. Two have the same size and the middle one has a different size. I tried targeting the element by accessing my class and then the image element.

I did have a working solution that gets all three centered and doesn't break either in responsive mode, by just using img and nothing else. But then the company logo on top of the homepage breaks.

I did also try using height but then I remembered that breaks in when I resize.

```
***.new-row {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}
.test {
    display: grid;
    width: auto;
    height: 700px;}
.new-row:hover {
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition: all;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 100%;
}
/* Commercial Text */
.top-left-column:hover {
  opacity: 96%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
.top-right-column:hover {
  opacity: 96%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
.bottom-left-column:hover {
  opacity: 96%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
.new-row div {
  display: flex; 
  width: 40%;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  opacity: 85%;
}
/* Text */
.container-text {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.new-row div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70%;
}
/* Fix for res2 not being the same length as the others */
.new-row div .top-right-column {
  height: inherit;
}
.center-text {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/gulam101/pen/jOWxdBQ

The codepen isn't using the images that I am trying to work with but rather just test images.

Comment: `img{ height: 200px}` ?

Comment: If I target the img then my logo will break on the homepage, but I have tried that method and it does work for my images. But then it presents a new problem for me. Thanks for giving me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add class to the `img`

```
<img class="myimg" .... >
```

and in css add a height to the img class

```
.myimg {
   height:200px
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I would upvote you but I don't have enough reputation. Thank you so much!